# Bash - Program is writing directly to terminal

Tags: linux, bash, debian, daemon

Valve's dedicated server for the Source Engine (srcds_run) on Linux writes directly to the terminal, not stdout. I want to run it as an /etc/init.d daemon on Debian 6, and I'd like to redirect/capture the output to a file. How can I do that? And better yet, why would they output directly to the terminal, is there any benefit in doing that?

I suppose I could start another bash instance just for srcds_run, but that seems like a dirty solution, and I still don't know how to redirect the output.

Comment: The script maybe is writing to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, check this running the script as: `./script 2>some_file`

Comment: If it is truly opening and writing to `/dev/tty` or something equivalent, rather than `stdout/stderr` or `cout/cerr`, you might need to run it inside a `screen` session (or `dtach` or other similar tools).

Comment: @h3nr1x I did try that already, it didn't work. Another odd annoying result is that if you run it as a background daemon you'll still get output in your terminal...

Comment: @twalberg is there a way to log to a file doing that though? I can't think of one, but I'm not terribly familiar with screen more than basics, and I've never heard of dtach

Comment: @twalberg nevermind, found it!

Answer (score 3):

Due to twalberg's helpful comment, I found the answer

Run the program in screen, and use screenlog (http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_17.html) to capture output

Comment: `screen -L -- command args...` saves output of the command to `screenlog.0`.